# Can't get Image URL from Google Ads API for HTML5 Ads

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to get access to Display Ad images via the Google Ads API.  At the moment, my code doesn't seem to be working for certain ads.  As near as I can tell from my debugging efforts so far, the issue is that it's not working for HTML5 ads.

Here is the query I'm using :

```
SELECT
     ad_group.name,
     campaign.name,
     ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_display_ad.logo_images,
     ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_display_ad.marketing_images,
     ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.preview_image_url,
     ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.image_url
FROM
    ad_group_ad
WHERE
    campaign.advertising_channel_type = \'DISPLAY\'
LIMIT
    100
```

For accounts using HTML5 ads, there is nothing returned for any of the last (4) fields.  For other accounts, I'm using the "ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.image_url" field to get the ad image.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`ad_group_ad.ad` has a pseudo-attribute `ad_data` which is a Union field that will have one specific, effective name depending on what [type of ad](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/google.ads.googleads.v3.enums#google.ads.googleads.v3.enums.AdTypeEnum.AdType) is represented. See the documentation of the [`Ad` resource](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/google.ads.googleads.v3.resources#ad).

Specifically, this means that all fields below `ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad` such as `image_url` will only be populated for an ad of type `IMAGE_AD`. Similarly, `ad.responsive_display_ad.*` will only contain data for ads with type `RESPONSIVE_DISPLAY_AD`.

For an HTML5 ad, you can access the available fields using the selector `ad_group_ad.ad.display_upload_ad`. You won't be able to obtain an image of the ad, however.